# Move column value and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not really sure how to word this, but I'm looking to move the values of one column to another row, based on a condition.

Some UnitNumbers have only one InsuranceIDs, and others have two.

I'd like to put second InsuranceID in their own column, but on the same row as the first.

I have this:

```
SELECT v.UnitNumber, InsuranceOrderID, ord.InsuranceID
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN BarInsuranceOrder ord
    ON ord.VisitID=v.VisitID
```

Which returns this:

```
UnitNumber  InsuranceOrderID    InsuranceID
----------  ----------------    -----------
M7090226          1             UNITEDMCD
M2133443          1             MCR
M2133443          2             NEWERASUP
M2173835          1             MCRCAREIMP
M2173835          2             MCD
M2179062          1             MCD
M2165847          1             AMERIGROUP
```

But I'm looking to return something like this:

```
UnitNumber  InsuranceID   SecondaryIns
----------  -----------   -----------
M7090226     UNITEDMCD
M2133443     MCR          NEWERASUP
M2173835     MCRCAREIMP   MCD
M2179062     MCD
M2165847     AMERIGROUP
```

This is as far as I've gotten, but I don't think it's going in the right direction:

```
SELECT v.UnitNumber
, (CASE WHEN InsuranceOrderID = '1' THEN ord.InsuranceID ELSE '-' END) [PrimaryIns]
, (CASE WHEN InsuranceOrderID = '2' THEN ord.InsuranceID ELSE '-' END) [SecondaryIns]
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN BarInsuranceOrder ord
    ON ord.VisitID=v.VisitID


UnitNumber  InsuranceID  SecondaryIns
----------  -----------  -----------
M7090226    UNITEDMCD    -
M2133443    MCR          -
M2133443    -            NEWERASUP
M2173835    MCRCAREIMP   -
M2173835    -            MCD
M2179062    MCD          -
M2165847    AMERIGROUP   -
```

I'm fairly new to SQL, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.  You just need aggregation:

```
SELECT v.UnitNumber,
       MAX(CASE WHEN InsuranceOrderID = 1 THEN ord.InsuranceID END) as [PrimaryIns],
       MAX(CASE WHEN InsuranceOrderID = 2 THEN ord.InsuranceID END) as [SecondaryIns]
FROM Visits v INNER JOIN
     BarInsuranceOrder ord
     ON ord.VisitID = v.VisitID
GROUP BY v.UnitNumber;
```

Notes:

- I removed the single quotes around the numbers.  Presumably the values are numeric and not strings.
- I removed the `ELSE`.  I figure `NULL` is good enough to get started -- and more consistent with your desired results.

Comment: This also works well too. No pivot required. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT UnitNumber, [1] InsuranceID,  [2]  SecondaryIns FROM
( 
    SELECT v.UnitNumber, InsuranceOrderID, ord.InsuranceID
    FROM Visits v
    INNER JOIN BarInsuranceOrder ord
        ON ord.VisitID=v.VisitID

 ) SRC
PIVOT (MAX(InsuranceID) FOR InsuranceOrderID IN ([1],[2]) )PVT
```

Result

```
UnitNumber InsuranceID SecondaryIns
---------- ----------- ------------
M7090226   UNITEDMCD   NULL
M2179062   MCD         NULL
M2173835   MCRCAREIMP  MCD
M2165847   AMERIGROUP  NULL
M2133443   MCR         NEWERASUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Join to itself and limit to the type you want.

```
SELECT v.UnitNumber, InsuranceOrderID, PrimaryIns.InsuranceID,SecIns.InsuranceID
FROM Visits v
INNER JOIN BarInsuranceOrder PrimaryIns
    ON ord.VisitID=v.VisitID and InsuranceOrderID =1
LEFT JOIN BarInsuranceOrder SecIns
    ON ord.VisitID=v.VisitID and InsuranceOrderID =2
```

Comment: Had to change it a little to run, but it's exactly what I needed. Thank you